# MySQL generate real-time counter grouped by parent ID

Tags: mysql, subquery, counter

I have two tables:

Parent Information & Dependent Information

The table structures are as follows:

### Parent

```
ID   |   First   |   Last   |   DOB       |   Address
-------------------------------------------------
1    |   John    |   Doe    | 1980-01-01  |   123 street
2    |   Ryan    |   Mack   | 1974-12-12  |   444 Place
```

### Dependents

```
ParentID   |    Type   |    First   |   Last    |    DOB
--------------------------------------------------
1    |   Spouse  |    Jane    |    Doe    |   1981-02-01
1    |   Child   |    Mike    |    Doe    |   1999-08-01
1    |   Child   |    Zoe     |    Doe    |   2002-04-01
2    |   Spouse  |    Sarah   |    Mack   |   1964-01-01
2    |   Child   |    Andrew  |    Mack   |   1997-05-01
```

I want to build a query (ideally single call with joins which returns the following:

### Table Results

```
First   |    Last    |    Type    |    DOB        |     Address
---------------------------------------------------------------- 
John    |    Doe     |    Parent  |  1980-01-01   |   123 Street
Jane    |    Doe     |    Spouse  |  1981-02-01   |   123 Street
Mike    |    Doe     |   Child    |  1999-08-01   |   123 street
Zoe     |    Doe     |   Child    |  2002-04-01   |   123 Street
Ryan    |    Mack    |  Parent    |  1974-12-12   |   444 Place
Sarah   |    Mack    |   Spouse   |  1964-01-01   |   444 Place
Andrew  |    Mack    |   Child    |  1997-05-01   |   444 Place
```

I am able to build the table above with help from another SO user with the following query:

```
SELECT t.First, t.Last, t.Type, t.DOB, t.Address
FROM (SELECT ID, First, Last, 'Parent' as Type, DOB, Address, 1 as SortKey
                 FROM Parent
            UNION ALL
            SELECT p.ID, d.First, d.Last, d.Type, d.DOB, p.Address, 
                         CASE WHEN d.Type = 'Spouse' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END as SortKey
                    FROM Dependents d
                            INNER JOIN Parent p
                                    ON d.ParentID = p.ID) t
ORDER BY t.ID, t.SortKey
```

I am trying to solve a (potentially) bigger issue in that I have to count each record for the particular member ID based on a few parameters.

Parents will always be 1,
Spouses will always be 2 (if they exist)
Children will start at 3 and continue until there are no more (if they exist).

My end table would look like:

```
First   |    Last    |    Type    |    DOB        |     Address  |   Count
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
John    |    Doe     |    Parent  |  1980-01-01   |   123 Street |  1
Jane    |    Doe     |    Spouse  |  1981-02-01   |   123 Street |  2
Mike    |    Doe     |   Child    |  1999-08-01   |   123 street |  3
Zoe     |    Doe     |   Child    |  2002-04-01   |   123 Street |  4
Ryan    |    Mack    |  Parent    |  1974-12-12   |   444 Place  |  1
Sarah   |    Mack    |   Spouse   |  1964-01-01   |   444 Place  |  2
Andrew  |    Mack    |   Child    |  1997-05-01   |   444 Place  |  3
```

I know I can set a user variable at the top of the call with say:

SET @counter:= 0;

THEN
@counter:=@counter+1 as counter,

but this would just continue the count all the way through the sql query instead of by ID.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.

```
SET @counter:= 0;
@counter:=@counter+1 as counter;
```

Almost does what you want, so why not change it to:

```
SET @counter:= 3;
SELECT
  inner_select.first
  ,inner_select.last
  ,inner_select.Type
  ,inner_select.DOB
  ,inner_select.Address
  ,CASE WHEN inner_select.SortKey IN (1,2) 
    THEN if(@counter:= 3 = 3,inner_select.SortKey,inner_select.SortKey)
   ELSE @counter:= @counter + 1 END as SortKey
FROM
(
  SELECT t.First, t.Last, t.Type, t.DOB, t.Address  
  FROM (SELECT ID, First, Last, 'Parent' as Type, DOB, Address, 1 as SortKey 
        FROM Parent
  UNION ALL
  SELECT p.ID, d.First, d.Last, d.Type, d.DOB, p.Address, 
    CASE WHEN d.Type = 'Spouse' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END as SortKey
  FROM Dependents d
  INNER JOIN Parent p ON d.ParentID = p.ID) t
  ORDER BY t.ID, t.SortKey 
) inner_select
ORDER BY inner_select.ID, inner_select.SortKey;
```

First we start with the @counter on 3, to start counting the kids.
Because the previous select is so close we select **from** that and tweak the result a little.
The `if (@count:= 3 = 3,i.sk,i.sk)` of course always gives `inner_select.sortKey` *(not the @counter)* as a result, but forces a reset of @counter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: seems logical - i'll have to try it out although, 4 subqueries in a single call might not be very efficient for us in the end (given how many rows and additional tables are effected). I want to run these in mysql as much as possible but it seems possibly building a basic php script to handle 2 calls (populate the parent, then populate his dependents) might be right way to go in the end.